# Problems with Tikz graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

This is my code

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[anchor=north] {$t[s]$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[anchor=east] {$q[C]$};
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=east] {$0$};

\draw[smooth, domain =0:6, samples = 500, color=blue] plot ({\x, 8*e^(-\x)-4*e^(-2*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It returns me an error. Can you tell me how to fix it, please?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a full MWE that we also know which packages you're using and so on. Usually there is a part of the document where you include the packages, make definitions and so no. This part is located before the `\begin{document}` section. The latter one is totally missing in your example. So it might be, that this is the reason. But I can't really tell without a proper MWE.

Comment: Set the braces differently: `\draw[smooth, domain =0:6, samples = 500, color=blue] plot 
(\x,{8*e^(-\x)-4*e^(-2*\x)});`. That is, surround the second component by `{...}`, and not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to plot an exponential curve.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={myexp(\x)=8*e^(-\x)-4*e^(-2*\x);}]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=left,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot [domain=0:6, samples = 500, color=blue] {myexp(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result
[image]